# Batch script variable issues - "VAR_%a"

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

The issue i'm having is at the very end on this specific line:

```
for %a in (*) do ren "%a" "%Text%_%a"
```

More specifically, this part:

```
"%Text%_%a"
```

I'm able to substitute the variable out for the specific value but I wanted the script to ask the question, with the input being set to a variable so that the code doesn't have to be manually modified for every occurrence.

Basically this is just a simple tool used to add prefixes, or any text to the beginning of a file name, in addition to what was there. 
For Example I would change documents 1 through 50 
to Document 1 through Document 50 
or Revision 1 through Revision 50

The Code

---

```
@echo off
set /p $path=What is the path: 
set /p $text=Text to add to the beginning of the file name?
set Text=%$text%
cd %$path%

echo[
echo Please verify that you are in the correct location.
echo You are currently in this directory:
echo[
cd
echo[
pause

for %a in (*) do ren "%a" "%Text%_%a"
```

Everything appears to be working fine, and the variable does appear to respond to the input when I do an echo %Text%, but it doesn't work in the final line. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have added the batch-file tag to your question in order that it receives appropriate attention. You have used `cmd.exe` syntax but as you're using it within a batch file, you need to double up your `%` characters, `for %%a in (*) do ren "%%a" "%Text%_%%a"`.